# Using chrome cURL from Linux terminal

Tags: google-chrome, curl

I want to download a file from terminal. Chrome can download the file and I used Chrome's cURL to extract the URL (and headers) it uses to download the file.

```
curl 'https://www.url.com/file.zip' -H 'authority: www.url.com' -H 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.84 Safari/537.36' -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' -H $'cookie: _ga=GA1.2.902526367.1545174559;' --compressed
```

But if I try to use the same thing from my command prompt it does nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using any URL shortening service? Did you get any error or response?

Comment: I'm using Chrome's Network feature to extract the cURL that it uses to download the file. It just hangs.. like missing additional parameter or sth.

Comment: But the URL used by you, is it shortened?

Comment: No, it's not...

Comment: Can you try by adding -v to see the verbose output.

Comment: prints '*   Trying the_ip_address'